# Cancel a nested Combine publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to switch my app to use a Combine pipeline. My hope was to simplify thread management, yet got myself into an unexpected behavior of Combine.

I assumed that despite the fact I am subscribing on DispatchQueue.global(), canceling the main pipeline would cancel the nested subscription.

Here is my playground:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Combine

let folders = ["folder1", "folder2", "folder3", "folder4"]

class OneByOnePublisher: Publisher {
    typealias Output = String
    typealias Failure = Never
    
    let input: [String]
    init(input: [String]) {
        self.input = input
    }
  
    func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Downstream.Input == Output, Downstream.Failure == Failure {
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
        subject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        for value in input {
            subject.send(value)
        }
        subject.send(completion: .finished)
    }
}

func uppercase(_ character: Character) -> String {
    print("Uppercasing \(character)")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
    return character.uppercased()
}

func uppercasePublisher(_ folder: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
    return folder.publisher
//        .handleEvents(receiveCancel: { print("Received cancel in nested") })
        .map{uppercase($0)}
        .collect()
        .map{$0.joined()}
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


let stringPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
let oneByOnePublisher = OneByOnePublisher(input: folders)


let cancelable = oneByOnePublisher
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .handleEvents(receiveCancel: { print("Received cancel in main") })
    .flatMap{uppercasePublisher($0)}
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { (completion) in
        print("Received completion: \(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { (value) in
        print("Received value: \(value)")
    }

Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
cancelable.cancel()
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
print("Done")
```

The output of that

```
Uppercasing f
Uppercasing o
Uppercasing l
Uppercasing d
Received cancel in main
Uppercasing e
Uppercasing r
Uppercasing 1
Done
```

However, if I uncomment the line with

```
//        .handleEvents(receiveCancel: { print("Received cancel in nested") })
```

Then the output is what I would expect in the first place

```
Uppercasing f
Uppercasing o
Uppercasing l
Uppercasing d
Received cancel in nested
Received cancel in main
Done
```

What am I missing? Why in the first case the nested subscription doesn't get immediately canceled? Why does adding handleEvents() changes the cancelation flow?

Comment: "Immediately" gets muddied here because you're subscribing on a concurrent queue.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't actually need to create a `OneByOnePublisher` publisher... Just doing `folders.publisher` would achieve the same result. Also, you don't need `uppercasePublisher` - you can achieve this with a simple `.map { uppercase($0) }`

Comment: Yeah, I created OneByOnePublisher just as an example. It closely mimics the actual design, which has a nested publisher and everything runs on the global queue.

Comment: For the immediate, I am fine with not stopping immediately, but it still should cancel the nested publisher in midstream. This is not happening for some reason, and the nested publisher keeps sending data.

Comment: The problem is that the cancel doesn't arrive "in time"... the values have already been emitted, and due to the concurrent nature you have a race condition.

Comment: Then why does it arrive in time when I have handleEvents()? From the debug output I can see that in the latter case the nested publisher stops emitting values.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, an extra `handleEvents` should not affect the cancellation process.

Answer (score 0):

Likely there is a bug with the `Publishers.Sequence` publisher, which is the one that results from the `folder.publisher` call. And adding the `handleEvents` call hides this bug as the call results in a wrapper publisher that seems to correctly handle the cancellation.

To put this theory to test, let's adapt your `OneByOnePublisher` to work with any kind of sequences (this will also make it work with the original array of strings):

```swift
class OneByOnePublisher<Seq: Sequence>: Publisher {
    typealias Output = Seq.Element
    typealias Failure = Never
    
    let input: Seq
    init(input: Seq) {
        self.input = input
    }
  
    func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Downstream.Input == Output, Downstream.Failure == Failure {
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
        subject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        for value in input {
            subject.send(value)
        }
        subject.send(completion: .finished)
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    var oneByOne: OneByOnePublisher<Self> { OneByOnePublisher(input: self) }
}
```

Now if we change `uppercasePublisher` to use the enhanced publisher

```swift
func uppercasePublisher(_ folder: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
    return folder.oneByOne
        // .handleEvents(receiveCancel: { NSLog("Received cancel in nested") })
        .map{uppercase($0)}
        .collect()
        .map{$0.joined()}
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

we can see that the cancellation works as expected, regardless the `handleEvents` line is commented or not. Which indicates that the original `folder.publisher` line was the source of the problem, and more specific - it was the `Publishers.Sequence` instance the problematic one.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for figuring out this puzzle.
I am not sure what exactly the bug is, but it actually not only .handleEvents() that avoids the bug, but print() as well.
Anyhow, thanks again!

Comment: @JkMu which `print` call are you referring to? If it's the one from the `receiveCancel` closure, then that's not the game changer, you could simply `.handleEvents()` with no arguments and see the same behaviour.

Comment: I mean that if you replace .handleEvents() with .print(), it will have the same effect on canceling.